# Python signal handler not called in multi-level threading ( two levels)

Tags: python-2.7, signals, python-multithreading

Python signal handler is not called when I used multilevel/nested( threading level 2) threading. Not sure exactly what is causing this. The relevant code is provided below.

As an alternative to multilevel/nested threading, I can try using either multiprocess+threading or Queue+threading. But I would really like to know the reason for this issue or any solution to the same. Seems like it has something to do with python Global Interpreter Lock(GIL).

Also what will be the best way of handling signals for multilevel threaded applications in python ?

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading, sys
import signal, time

threads = []
threadsL1 = []
threadsL1_statusflag = False
stopExecutionFlag = False


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    global stopExecutionFlag
    def __init__(self, name):
    super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self._tname = name
    self._terminate = False

    #threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def terminate(self):
    print "L2[%s] : calling terminate" % self._tname
    self._terminate = True
    stopExecutionFlag = True

    def run(self):
    print "L2[%s]: Running" % self._tname
    while True:
        if stopExecutionFlag: 
        print "L2[%s] : stopExecutionFlag is set. Exiting now !!"
        break
        print "L2[%s]: Sleeping for 2 sec" % self._tname
        time.sleep(2)

    print "L2[%s]: Thread stopped" % self._tname


def startThreadL2(name):
    global threads
    print "L1[%s] Inside startThreadL2" % name
    t1 = MyThread(name)
    t1.start()
    threads.append(t1)
    print "L2[%s] Thread started and appended to threads array" % name

def joinThreadsL2():
    global threads
    print "L2 Inside joinThreadsL2()"
    for thread in threads:
    thread.join()    
    print "All threads finished execution"

def stopThreadsL2():
    global stopExecutionFlag
    stopExecutionFlag = True

    print "Inside stopThreadsL2()"
    joinThreadsL2()

def startThreadL1_and_wait():
    global threadsL1
    print "Main() calling startThreadL1()"
    for i in range(1,3):
    t1 =  threading.Thread(target=startThreadL2, args=("T%d" % i,))
    t1.start()
    threadsL1.append(t1)
    print "L1[%s] : Thread started" % ("T%d" % i)

    print "L1[%s] : Waiting for all threads to finish"
    for t2 in threadsL1:
    t2.join()
    print "L1[%s] : All L1 threads finished"
    threadsL1_statusflag = True

def stopThreadsL1():
    global threadsL1_statusflag
    if not threadsL1_statusflag:
    print "L1[%s] : Waiting for all threads to finish"
    for t2 in threadsL1:
        t2.join()
    print "L1[%s] : All L1 threads finished" 
        threadsL1_statusflag = True

def terminate(signum, frame):
    print "\n------------------------------ Inside terminate()-------------------------\n\n"
    stopThreadsL2()
    stopThreadsL1()
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    m_threads = []

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, terminate)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, terminate)

    print "\n-----------------------Inside main thread------------------------\n"
    startThreadL1_and_wait()

    print "\n------------------------- All L1 threads started. Press Ctrl+C to stop !!------------------------\n"
    joinThreadsL2() 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<pre>
reynold@heuristics:~/test$ python test_threading.py 

    -----------------------Inside main thread------------------------

    Main() calling startThreadL1()
    L1[T1] Inside startThreadL2
     L1[T1] : Thread started
    L2[T1]: Running
     L2[T1] Thread started and appended to threads array
    L2[T1]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L1[T2] Inside startThreadL2
     L2[T2]: Running
     L2[T2]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T2] Thread started and appended to threads array
    L1[T2] : Thread started
    L1[%s] : Waiting for all threads to finish
    L1[%s] : All L1 threads finished

    ------------------------- All L1 threads started. Press Ctrl+C to stop !!------------------------

    L2 Inside joinThreadsL2()
    L2[T2]: Sleeping for 2 sec
     L2[T1]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T2]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T1]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T2]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T1]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    ^CL2[T2]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T1]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    ^CL2[T2]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T1]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    ^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^CL2[T2]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    L2[T1]: Sleeping for 2 sec
    ^C^Z
    [1]+  Stopped                 python test_threading.py
    reynold@heuristics:~/test$ kill -9 %1

    [1]+  Stopped                 python test_threading.py
    reynold@heuristics:~/test$ 
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the exact same issue in 3.6 and the solution I found was to first set SIG_IGN in main then after the threads have been created, set your own handler.

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_IGN)
worker.start()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
```

This is an odd issue indeed, calling the top level class (that directly inherits threading) doesn't break signal, but any lower level classes require a workaround.